# Run git add and commit on Openshift Server

Tags: git, openshift

I'm working with a platform that creates a configuration.php file as part of the instillation process.  Right now, the installation process is run as part of the build hook on the server.  The problem is that because its being created on the server, after every push, it has to rerun the instillation process.  This overwrites a lot of the changes.

Is there a way to run `git add` and `git commit` on the server?  If I can add the configuration.php file to the repo and `git pull` it down, then the instillation process won't continue to run. If so, what directory should I run the commands in?

I've tried SSHing onto the server and running the git commands, but only receive the error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)` no matter what directory I try.

Comment: I read your question several times but I still don't understand what is the problem here and what you're trying to do. In general, yes you can do `git add` and `git commit` on the server, and I see you don't seem to know where your Git repo directory is on the server, but this is all I understood from your explanation.

Comment: Openshift is a cloud paas and its different than most hosts.  I know I should be able to access the git repo easily, but haven't had any luck at it yet.  Was hoping someone might know why or how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that once you push your commits to the OpenShift repo, the OpenShift server automatically starts a fresh installation and you loose all your configurations and data?

This is OpenShift's way of enforcing a correct deployment process. You shouldn't try to bypass it; rather, you should adapt your installation to it. If your deployment process can work well with OpenShift, you can easily deploy multiple environments and keep them up-to-date, which can be a life-saver once you hit production.

I also faced this problem, and this is what I did:

The key is the `app-root/data` folder. This folder does not get deleted when you push, so you can use it to store data files that shouldn't change when you deploy. I also used it to store my configuration files. I put the configuration files in the `.gitignore`, so they don't get checked out into the OpenShift repo. Then, I used the `build` hook (though maybe I should have used `pre_build`...) to copy those files from the `data` folder to their true location, before I started building.

What you need to remember is that every file needed for the build should be either versioned by git, copied from `data`, downloaded from the internet (by a dependency manager or by `wget` \ `curl`) or created during the build process. You can't have files that just stay there (like you have in the local working copy on your development machine), so if you have a file that isn't versioned and isn't created during the build process - make sure you set a hook to download it or copy it from `data`.

If you need a reference, you can take a peek at my project. The relevant parts are [the action hooks](http://code.google.com/p/ilender/source/browse/#git%2F.openshift%2Faction_hooks) and [this instructions document](http://ilender.googlecode.com/git/docs/open-shift_installation.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I know that everything needs to be part of the repo, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to manage this file.

I've tried using the data directory instead, but the files are always 777.  I've tried chmoding the files, but they'd always revert back.  That's not good for configuration files that contain sensitive information.  Maybe I'm missing something in that regard; I'll research farther.

Comment: Why would you even care about those permissions? OpenShift is not a terminal server - it doesn't have end-users that mess around with stuff. Each OpenShift account has a single user, and only that user can SSH into the projects. Even if you have multiple SSL keys, they will all share the same user on the OpenShift machine. That user(=you) only logins via SSH as an admin with a clear goal in mind, so I wouldn't worry about accidentally modifying those files. Other users can't even access that directory tree. That leaves the RedHat guys who run OpenShift - and they won't mess up your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I installed a PHP forum on my OpenShift server. To solve the issue of losing your configuration files when pushing to your remote git:

1. Install your platform and let it create it's PHP configuration files and make changes to your remote git.
2. Use [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to download your remote repo to your local git. For example, use a command similar to: `pscp -r -i "x:\your\private\key\location\id_rsa.ppk" your.openshift.host:app-root/runtime/repo/* "x:\your\local\git\location"`
3. Commit changes (and configuration files) to your local git.
4. Push commit to your remote git.

Now when you push your remote git, you will push your configuration files as well. Note that if your platform makes additional changes to your remote git, you will have to repeat the above so that you don't lose them when you push.